# How to repeat subreport in each page?

Tags: reporting-services, repeat, subreport

I Have 2 .rdl files (A.rdl and B_Subreport.rdl), A.rdl is calling B.Subreport.rdl using subreport control and also have a tablix separate with subreport. Tablix header is repeating in all the pages, i want that subreport will also repeat with tablix header but its not working.

Pls guide me how to repeat subreport in all page like tablix header?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve this by adding another tablix header row to your tablix.
Make sure this row has only 1 column and replace the `TextBox` of the cell with a `Rectangle`.

Now you can place your subreport into the tablix header and it will also be repeated on every page if the `RepeatRowHeaders` is set to true.

---

**EDIT**: Added image for visual help.

[image]

Comment: Thanks u for ur reply, but I want my Subreport seperate with my tablix u can see the attach file.

Comment: Well, you make sure that it is inside the top most table header row and remove the borders. You can add another empty rectangle just below your subreport (inside the table header row) that adds some white space below your subreport. Or  even add a third table header row between the subreport and the actual table header to mimic the empty space.